# issue with httpclient request Array in Angular

Tags: angular, wordpress, api

I am using httpclient request to get data from wordpress API, and in response I am getting error. It seems issue with Array in response.
here what is the code I am using

```
getTetimonialData() {
    this.http.get<{ testimonials: any }>(BASE_URL + '/testimonial/').pipe( map( testimonialsData => {
      // return testimonialsData;
      return {
        testimonials: testimonialsData.testimonials.map(testData => {
          return {
            id: testData.id,
            date: testData.date,
            slug: testData.slug,
            title: {
              rendered: testData.title.rendered,
            },
            yoast_meta: {
              yoast_wpseo_title: testData.yoast_meta.yoast_wpseo_title,
              yoast_wpseo_metadesc: testData.yoast_meta.yoast_wpseo_metadesc,
              yoast_wpseo_canonical: testData.yoast_meta.yoast_wpseo_canonical,
            },
            acf: {
              video_url: testData.acf.video_url,
              video_image: {
                url: testData.acf.video_image.url,
                alt: testData.acf.video_image.alt,
              }
            }
          };
        })
      };
    })).subscribe(transformData => {
      this.testimonials = transformData.testimonials;
      console.log(this.testimonials);
      this.testimonialFetch.next(this.testimonials);
    });
  }
```

and here is the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I have even tried to use `tesimonialData.map` as response is already in Array, but this also shows warring that testimonial type any not allowed.

This Error is for line where i am looping through data not with the rxjs map function.

so is I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Please see https://angular.io/guide/http and try to structure your code that way also I would suggest to use typescript Interface  instead of mapping it to a JSON

Comment: Can you show a representation of what your `testimonialsData` looks like when you `console.log(...)` it?

Comment: Is the map import correct? what version of rxjs do you use?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel testimonialData is an Array here is the link of http resquest
http://triadofhealth.websitehelpdesk.in/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/testimonial

Comment: @puntacrm yes it is imported from rxjs/operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET request type is incorrect. Below is a pic from the URL you shared in the comments.

[image: API Response]

Instead of `this.http.get<{ testimonials: any }>...` it should be of type `this.http.get<any[]>...` since the response is a list of the testimonials and not an object with a `testimonials` property. Ideally you would have an interface to use for type safety, so instead of `any[]` it would maybe be `ServerTestimonial[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please answer this question as well
[Angular Resolver issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56113847/10334068)

Sorry don't have much reputation to comment