# Angular Resolver issue

Tags: angular, wordpress, api

I am working on angular project where I get Home page ID from ACF options,
and then need to send another HTTP request to that page ID.

I have created angular Resolver, but I don't know how to send this multiple request

Is there a way to get home page from option end point and then pass to pages endpoint.

here is the code what I am trying.

```
export class HomeResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    this.http.get<any>(ACF_OPTIONS).subscribe((res) => {
      return this.http.get<any>(HOME_PAGE + res.acf.home_page).pipe(map((optionsData: any) => {
        return optionsData;
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

But this code return is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not returning an observable anymore, since you are subscribing already inside the resolver.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.http.get<any>(ACF_OPTIONS).pipe(
        switchMap(res) => this.http.get<any>(HOME_PAGE + res.acf.home_page)
    );
}
```

You should now receive the return of the second http call inside your resolved params in the route parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this with a plugin of mine, [Xo for Angular](https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core/blob/master/Includes/Api/Controllers/PostsController.class.php), which provides an integrated approach to loading an Angular App as a normal theme within WordPress.

The overall problem is that the WP Rest API doesn't provide an endpoint for looking up pages and their data using the requested URL. This creates a situation similar to the above where it is necessary to keep track of the ID of a given page/post which can be problematic down the road.

I use the following (simplified) approach in the [XoPostsController](https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core/blob/master/Includes/Api/Controllers/PostsController.class.php):

```
<?php

$post_id = 0;

// Check if the url is for the home page
if ($_GET['url'] == '/') {
    $post_id = get_option('page_on_front', 0);
}

// Translate the url to a post id
if (!$post_id) {
    $post_id = url_to_postid($_GET['url']);
}

// Get the wordpress post object if the post was found
if ($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
}

// Attempt to get the page by the url
if (!$post) {
    $post = get_page_by_path($_GET['url']);
}

echo json_encode($post);
```

Then a simplified resolver based on [XoPostResolver](https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-node/blob/master/lib/src/services/posts/post.resolver.ts) of the API:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { XoPosts } from '../api/posts/posts';
import { XoApiPostsService } from '../api/posts/posts.service';

@Injectable()
export class XoPostResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private _postService: XoApiPostsService) { }

    resolve(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = ((_route.data.url) ? (_route.data.url) : _state.url.split(/[?#]/)[0]);
            this._postService.get(url).subscribe((response: XoPosts.PostsGetResponse) => {
                if (response.success)
                    resolve(response.post);
                reject();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully that works!